# Администраторы БД, разработчики приложений, разработчики БД, конечные пользователи - кто есть кто, кто чем занимается?

Tags: база-данных

Собственно теория...
Пользователи СУБД делятся на четыре различные группы:

1. администраторы баз данных.
2. разработчики приложений;
3. разработчики баз данных;
4. конечные пользователи;

Я так понимаю:
- админы БД создают СУБД (напр. MS Access);
- разработчики БД с помощью того же Access создают структуру и логику БД;
- конечные пользователи наполняют БД инфой и пользуются для своих нужд;

НО кто тогда разработчики приложений?

Comment: Админы создают СУБД? Ха-ха. Пока все вкалывают в поте лица как папы Карлы, админы только пиво успевают заливать за воротник. Известен только один админ, который что-то создал - автор nginx Игорь Владимирович Сысоев

Answer (score 1):

Разработчики приложений в *данном контексте* создают приложения, которые позволяют пользователям

> наполнять БД инфой и пользоваться для своих нужд,

не отвлекая разработчиков и админов БД от их деятельности.

Answer (score 1):

**Адмиинстратор базы данных** - специалист, который проектирует базу данных, разрабатывает требования к ней, занимается ее реализацией, эффективным использованием и сопровождением, например, управлением учетными записями пользователей БД, защитой от несанкционированного доступа к данным, хранящимся в базе, поддержкой их целостности.

**Разработчики приложений**, такие же конечные пользователи базы данных, но вместе с администратором который занимается проектированием, согласовывают необходимые предстоящие изменения в базе для поддержания бизнес-процессов.

**Разработчики базы данных** - разрабатывают конечный программный продукт в виде базы данных, а также внутренние алгоритмы хранения и управления данными в этом программном продукте и т.д.